# Tranferring User Stories from Rally (CA Agile Central) to Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops, rally

I have been using Rally (CA Agile Central) for a little over a year now. I am looking for some way to transfer all of my User Stories from Agile to Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online). The links on the Rally site don't seem to work at all, does anyone know of a good way to do this? I need to do this once, not keep it in sync.
I found OpsHub, which says it can do this, but its a synchronization service that costs way too much. Looking for the one time transfer solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Microsoft TFS 2015 for Work Items](https://help.rallydev.com/rally-connector-microsoft-tfs-test-management) to do this.

> The connector provides five services to synchronize objects between CA
>   Agile Central and TFS:
>
> - Copy work items created in TFS to CA Agile Central (defects, user stories, or test cases only)
> - Copy work items created in CA Agile Central (defects, user stories, tasks, or test cases only) to TFS work items
> - Update CA Agile Central work items based on changes made in TFS
> - Update TFS work items based on changes made to CA Agile Central work items
> - Update CA Agile Central fields and TFS fields (may not be used in conjunction with the other update services)

Refer to this link for details: [Microsoft TFS 2015 for Work Items Installation & User Guide](https://help.rallydev.com/microsoft-tfs-work-items-installation-user-guide).

Comment: Is there any sample configuration files out there to handle the status/reason fields, really any of the fields? I was hoping to find a starting template that gets the basics, but there doesn't seem to be any.